# Finding path in Minimum Cost Path algo using Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic, path, shortest-path

- Given a cost matrix cost[][] and a position (m, n) in cost[][], write
  a function that returns cost of minimum cost path to reach (m, n)
  from (0, 0).
- Each cell of the matrix represents a cost to traverse through that
  cell. Total cost of a path to reach (m, n) is sum of all the costs on
  that path (including both source and destination).
- You can only traverse down, right and diagonally lower cells from a
  given cell, i.e., from a given cell (i, j), cells (i+1, j), (i, j+1)
  and (i+1, j+1) can be traversed.
- You may assume that all costs are positive integers.

**I was able to find the minimum cost and this article turned out to be very helpful:**

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-6-min-cost-path/

[image: dp]
<sub>(source: [cloudfront.net](http://d2o58evtke57tz.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/dp2.png))</sub>

**But it does not tell the actual path that must be followed which in the above example is (0, 0) –> (0, 1) –> (1, 2) –> (2, 2).
How can I find the path?**

Comment: Just keep track of which cell is the parent...

Comment: You could accept the correct answer; stating that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

When you're searching for the path, also keep track of the decisions that you're making, i.e. when you're selecting the minimum in this statement (taken from the article you're referencing):

```
return cost[m][n] + min( minCost(cost, m-1, n-1),
                           minCost(cost, m-1, n),
                           minCost(cost, m, n-1) );
```

You also need to keep track of which element was the minimum (e.g. in a separate matrix with directions (left, up, up-left)). Then you can backtrack from the final element of the matrix and reconstruct the path.

This is basically Levenshtein distance with back-tracking, you can find a pseudo-code implementation e.g. [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frank/csc401/tutorials/Levenshtein.pdf)

Comment: `min( minCost(cost, m-1, n-1),
    minCost(cost, m-1, n),
    minCost(cost, m, n-1) );`

Using the above formula I will find many minimum elements (one out of every three) but that doesn't means all of them would be a part of the final path.

Can you share some kind of pseudo-code for you approach?

Answer (score 0):

As we keep the track using arrows in logest common subsequence problem using an auxillary array, similarly here we can keep track of which element returned the minimum value. Then starting from cell (m,n) backtrack as per the arrows you have stored.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @StarsSky This does provide an answer if I didn't get it wrong. Here is my solution: http://ideone.com/i3AtVG